# Shell Script - While Loop / File Reading not working

Tags: bash, shell

I have a requirement which should address following points.

1. I have a file which contains list of IP addresses,I want to read line by line.
2. For each IP I need to push following commands using SSH (all are Mikrotik devices)

   ```
      / radius add service=login address=172.16.0.1 secret=aaaa
     / user aaa set use-radius=yes
   ```

Following is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="branch"

while IFS= read line; do

        echo ${line//}
        line1=${line//}
        ok='@'
        line3=$ok$line1

        sshpass -p abc123 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin$line3 / radius add service=login address=172.16.0.1 secret=aaaa
        sleep 3
        sshpass -p abc123 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin$line3 / user aaa set use-radius=yes
        sleep 3
        echo $line3
        echo $line
done <"$filename"
```

Branch text file:

```
192.168.100.1

192.168.101.2

192.168.200.1
```

Issue: What ever the changes I am doing While loop is only run once.

Troubleshooting/Observations:
Without the SSH command if I run the While loop to read the file " branch " it work fine.

Comment: Don't use `sshpass`!! Prefer understand how *``public key authentication''* doe work!! (Nota: `sshpass` may be the cause of your strange problem)

Comment: Do you have blank lines in your input file as you show?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a program in the loop also reads data on standard input. This will consume the 2nd and subsequent lines of what's in `"$filename"`.
On the next iteration of the loop, there's nothing left to read and the loop terminates.

The solution is to identify the command reading stdin, probably `sshpass` and change it to leave stdin alone. The answer by Cyrus shows one way to do that for `ssh`. If that doesn't work, try

```
sshpass [options and arguments here] < /dev/null
```

Another solution is to replace the `while` with a `for` loop. This works as long as the `branch` file only contains IP addresses:

```
 for ip in $(cat branch); do
    echo $ip
    ...
    sshpass ...
 done
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) :) One thing to clarify ... I need to know what you meant by " **The problem is that a program in the loop also reads data on standard input. This will consume the 2nd and subsequent lines of what's in "$filename". On the next iteration of the loop, there's nothing left to read and the loop terminates.** "

Comment: It means that both the `read` and the `sshpass` read from the same standard input, namely the from `"$filename"`. First comes the `read`, it reads the first line in filename; then comes sshpass, which reads all the remaining lines. Then the next `read` has nothing more to read and terminates the loop.